# DAX Multiple filters across multiple columns to produce new table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio, filterfunction

I am using Power BI and I have a table with multiple Columns and Rows that I want to filter with DAX. I want to filter across two columns based on their string value to produce a new table showing the complete row of data that fit both criteria.

For example (I know this is wrong) I want to write something like:

Measure = FILTER('Table 1', [Column1] = "Red" && [Column2] = "Blue")
....Then show a new table of rows containing their full range of data but only those rows that fit both Red and Blue criteria.

Please help.